# Woocommerce Price Text

Tags: php, functions, filters, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm trying to show after the price of my product, whether the price is 'per person' or 'per group'.

I've created a custom field for both, so for example, if custom field 'price_per_person' is ticked, price would display as $100 **per person** or if custom field 'price_per_person' is ticked, price would display as $100 **per group**

I've started with the filter below, but all the queries I have done to identify whether the custom field is selected have not worked.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_price_html', 100, 2 );
function custom_price_html( $price, $product ){
    $price = $price . ' per person';
    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_price', $price );
}
```

Thanks!

Update with Output

```
Array
(
    [_edit_last] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

    [_edit_lock] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1428754721:1
        )

    [_visibility] => Array
        (
            [0] => visible
        )

    [_stock_status] => Array
        (
            [0] => instock
        )

    [total_sales] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
        )

    [_downloadable] => Array
        (
            [0] => no
        )

    [_virtual] => Array
        (
            [0] => no
        )

    [_regular_price] => Array
        (
            [0] => 79
        )

    [_sale_price] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [_purchase_note] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [_featured] => Array
        (
            [0] => no
        )

    [_weight] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [_length] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [_width] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [_height] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [_sku] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [_product_attributes] => Array
        (
            [0] => a:0:{}
        )

    [_sale_price_dates_from] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [_sale_price_dates_to] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [_price] => Array
        (
            [0] => 79
        )

    [_sold_individually] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [_manage_stock] => Array
        (
            [0] => no
        )

    [_backorders] => Array
        (
            [0] => no
        )

    [_stock] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [_upsell_ids] => Array
        (
            [0] => a:0:{}
        )

    [_crosssell_ids] => Array
        (
            [0] => a:0:{}
        )

    [_product_image_gallery] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [slide_template] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [_thumbnail_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 63
        )

    [_wpb_vc_js_status] => Array
        (
            [0] => false
        )

    [_wpb_vc_js_interface_version] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
        )

    [price_per_person] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

    [_price_per_person] => Array
        (
            [0] => field_5528e5f80bad0
        )

    [price_per_group] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
        )

    [_price_per_group] => Array
        (
            [0] => field_5528e6580bad1
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `$product` parameter to get the custom field value, and determine what to return:

```
function custom_price_html( $price, $product ) {
    if ( ( int ) get_post_meta( $product->id, 'price_per_person', true ) )
        $price .= ' per person';
    elseif ( ( int ) get_post_meta( $product->id, 'price_per_group', true ) )
        $price .= ' per group';

    $price .= '[filtered]'; // For debugging - if you don't see this next to your prices, the filter isn't even running, hence why it's not working!

    return $price;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_price_html', 500, 2 );
```

This is assuming that you save each "checked" state under its own meta key, and that if a state is not checked, the field does not exist or is "empty".

It might actually make more sense to use one meta field `price_type`, and then save a value of `per_person` or `per_group` depending on the checked state (since a price can't actually be both types, can it?).

**Update:** To debug the situation, place this in your `functions.php`, view the product in your browser, then update your question with the output:

```
function wpse_183901_debug_product() {
    if ( is_singular( 'product' ) ) {
        echo '<pre>';
        echo esc_html( print_r( get_post_meta( get_queried_object_id() ), true ) );
        echo '</pre>';
        exit;
    }
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse_183901_debug_product' );
```

Comment: I have checked under one of the two states, but it doesn't display any result. 

Yes, in theory there only needs to be one meta field... how would I structure the query?

Thanks

Comment: You need to first confirm that your checked states are being correctly saved in the database, and under which keys are they?

Comment: The keys are both checkboxes 
1. is price_per_person
2. is price_per_group
Field group is 'Pricing Type' if that helps?

Comment: So you're using ACF?

Comment: I need to know how exactly you've configured it. Are you using "True / False", or "Checkbox" (and if the latter, what option values).

Comment: ACF will store `0` if unchecked, `1` if checked. My code should work. Something else is at play here. Try `print_r( get_post_meta( $product->id ) )` and it'll print out all meta for that product.

Comment: I've tried to use the print_r function in a few places but get no results anywhere...

Comment: See my revision.

Comment: Done. Pls see question

Comment: The data is all there. I've updated my original solution with a slight modification. If that doesn't work, something else is at fault.